# What length of passwords do rainbow tables go to?

Tags: passwords, password-protection, rainbowtable, rainbowattack

My bank limits my password to 14 characters and I suspect they're encrypting with MD5 or an SHA hash, unsalted.

Are there rainbow tables that contain every possible hash up to 14 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the character ranges used, but 10 characters seems to be the limit in the [the downloads here](http://www.freerainbowtables.com/en/tables2/) (lower for full character ranges).

Comment: Cool. Looks like the only way to get up to 14 characters is if it's numbers only, or some other unusual character restriction. It would be interesting to look at when they'll get to 14 chars for full-character range passwords, taking into consideration advanced hardware and moores law.